# Reading file into double int pointer

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, pointer-to-pointer

I'm trying to read a file into an array but I'm getting segmentation fault, I know I'm not allocating memory correctly. What am I doing wrong here?. I'm allowed to use `read()` and `while` loop.

**EDIT**

my complete function, before I split in into two parts

```
int     **ft_create_map(char *filename, int nb_cols, int nb_rows)
{
    int     **map;
    int     fd;
    int     row;
    int     col;
    ssize_t size;
    char    buf[BUF_SIZE];

    row = 0;
    size = 0;
    col = 0;
    map = (int **)malloc(nb_rows * sizeof(int *));
    if (!map)
            return (map);
            map[0] = malloc(sizeof(int) * nb_cols);
            fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
            if (!fd)
                    return (NULL);
                    while ((size = read(fd, buf, BUF_SIZE)))
                    {
                            if (size < 1)
                                    return (NULL);
                            buf[size] = '\0';
                            if (buf[0] == '\n')
                            {
                                    row += 1;
                                    col = 0;
                                    map[row] = malloc(sizeof(int) * nb_cols);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                    if (buf[0] == '.')
                                            map[row][col] = 1;
                                    else if (buf[0] == 'o')
                                            map[row][col] = 0;
                                    col++;
                            }
                    }
    return (map);
 }
```

Here I'm trying to split the previous function into two functions, because my functions needs to have less than 25 lines of code.

```
void fill_map(int **map,int fd, int row, int col)
{
    ssize_t size;
    char    buf[BUF_SIZE];

    size = 0;
    while ((size = read(fd, buf, BUF_SIZE)))
    {
        if (size < 1)
           // return (0); commented out for testing
        buf[size] = '\0';
        if (buf[0] == '\n')
        {
            //this was the problem, allocating memory to map[0] twice.
            row += 1;
            map[row] = malloc(sizeof(int) * (col + 1));
            col = 0;
        }
        else
       {
           if (buf[0] == '.')
              map[row][col] = 1;
           else if (buf[0] == 'o')
              map[row][col] = 0;
           col++;
       }
    }
 }

 int        **ft_create_map(char *filename, int nb_cols, int nb_rows)
 {
    int     **map;
    int     fd;
    int     row;
    int     col;
    ssize_t size;
    // char buf[BUF_SIZE];

    row = 0;
    size = 0;
    col = 0;
    map = (int **)malloc(nb_rows * sizeof(int *));
    if (!map)
       return (map);
    map[0] = malloc(sizeof(int) * nb_cols);
    fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
    if (!fd)
       return (NULL);
    fill_map(map, fd, row, col);
    return (map);
 }
```

in my main

```
int cols = count_cols(argv[1]);
int rows = count_rows(argv[1]);
int **arr;
// int  j;
// int i;

arr = ft_create_map(argv[1], cols, rows);
printf_max_square(arr, rows, cols);
```

[code ideone](http://ideone.com/sft2Nb)

Comment: Where does it crash ?

Comment: in the `fill_map` function.

Comment: Show the code where you call `ft_create_map`.

Comment: Which environnment do you use ? Linux, gcc, Windows, Turbo C, .... ??

Comment: I use `clang` and `gcc` on `OS X`

Comment: Use the gdb debugger which will tell you at which line the segfault occurs.

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: could `size` be -1 after the `read()`? I would expect `buf[-1] = '\0';` to segfault

Comment: no `i don't think so, the file is valid.

Comment: That `if (size < 1)` is super weird because the next condition is never gonna happen then. Also for the love of god, stop casting malloc returns. Also why do you only ever check the first character of buf ? is `BUF_SIZE = 2` ?

Comment: You should ***really*** add a test for `size == -1`! This is debugging for free ... *sigh*

Comment: Also you want to learn how to use a debugger, then step through the code inspecting all relevant variables to see what is *really* going on.

Comment: What's the content of the file you are reading?

Comment: Doubt it's related to the segfault, but it looks like you have a potential memory leak. In `ft_create_map` you have `map[0] = malloc(sizeof(int) * nb_cols);` Then in `fill_map` you have `map[row] = malloc(sizeof(int) * (col + 1));` where `row==0`. So this will be a mem leak if `buf[0] == '\n'`.

Comment: @yano that was the problem, thanks for pointing that out. can you please write that as an answer?

Comment: oh interesting,, really wouldn't have expected that to segfault heh,, but I don't know your program flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a potential memory leak. In `ft_create_map you have map[0] = malloc(sizeof(int) * nb_cols);` Then in fill_map you have `map[row] = malloc(sizeof(int) * (col + 1));` where `row==0`. So this will be a mem leak if `buf[0] == '\n'`.

Actually kind of surprised to hear (from the OP) that this is also causing a segfault, but maybe that would become obvious if we knew the exact program flow.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this line gets commented in

```
 // return (0); commented out for testing
```

the moment `read()` returns `BUF_SIZE`, this line

```
buf[size] = '\0';
```

writes out of `buf`'s bounds and with this invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: We don't know what `BUF_SIZE` is (maybe it's 0??), but with the code provided, shouldn't `buf[size] = '\0';` only get executed if size < 1? As soon as `// return (0)` is uncommented out I completely agree with this.

Comment: @yano: Correct, adjusted my answer. However, I know those guys ... ;-)

Comment: the problem is not the `buf[size]`, this doesn't have any effect, I can remove or leave it, the program will still runs.

Comment: @Phuti: If it continues running, that's just bad luck. It still might crash two years later ... assuming it ran so long. ;-)

Comment: @Phuti Well, that's a dangerous game, the whole point is it's UB, so when combined with Murphy's law that means it will _always_ work when you run it for yourself and _never_ work during a demo for your boss/customer or the TA who's grading it.